# which is the error in this query?

Tags: sql

I do not know why this query is not working properly as I could not find the error

```
SELECT U.user_name, 
  COUNT(*) AS fav_count 
FROM Users AS U 
LEFT JOIN Favorites AS F 
  ON F.user_id = U.user_id;
```

thank you very much, and sorry for my bad English!

Comment: "not working properly" is an incredibly vague question. In the future, describe what it's doing that's wrong, or what error you get. (In practice, that would make the error -- a missing GROUP BY clause -- incredibly obvious).

Answer (score 10):

You can't mix normal column selects with aggregate functions like `count()` when you don't use a `group by` clause. This works

```
SELECT U.user_name, COUNT(*) AS fav_count 
FROM Users AS U 
LEFT JOIN Favorites AS F ON F.user_id = U.user_id
group by U.user_name
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not grouping by the `U.user_name`

Answer (score 1):

Change the query to:

```
SELECT U.user_name, COUNT(F.user_id) AS fav_count 
FROM Users AS U 
LEFT JOIN Favorites AS F ON F.user_id = U.user_id
GROUP BY U.user_name
```

This resolves two problems:

1. You need to use `GROUP BY` to get per-user counts.
2. In the `COUNT()` expression, you should specify a column in the `LEFT JOIN` table so that null rows will not be counted. Otherwise, you'll get `fav_count = 1` for users with no favorites.

Answer (score 0):

you must use group by when using this command in select  sum(),count(),avg(),max()